# what \\s matches in Java

Tags: java, regex

In all the tutorials I have read they always say that \s matches a whitespace. So why this instruction

```
System.out.println("line1   \n   line2".replaceAll("\\s\\s*", " "));
```

have this output :

```
line1 line2
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: What would you expect it to return?

Comment: I expect : line1 \n line1

Comment: `\n` is whitespace, as others have said.  If you only want to replace spaces, then use a space instead of `\\s`; if you want to replace spaces and tabs, then `[ \\t]` instead of `\\s`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string literal `"\\s\\s*"` is equivalent to the [regular expression syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\s\s*` which matches "a whitespace character followed by zero or more whitespace characters".

A whitespace character is defined as `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`, which includes spaces *and* newlines.

Comment: And `\s\s*` is the same as `\s+`.

Comment: What's \x0B character

Comment: @user230137 `\x0B` is "Vertical Tab" (VT) in ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

`\\s` matches a whitespace character, where the whitespace characters are - `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. It's not just a space. I suspect this is what you inferred from whitespace. See [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class documentation.

Also, you can replace your regex `\\s\\s*` with just `\\s+`.

Answer (score 2):

`"\\s\\s*"` is the escaped version of `\s\s*` which is the same of `\s+`

It maches one or more of any white-space char. White-space chars are `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. So it will replace multiple white-spaces by only one in each match.

Answer (score 1):

First, this regex is a bit silly: `\\s\\s*` will match one or more whitespace characters, since the `\\s` character class matches all whitespace.

But, it could be expressed easier as `\\s+`, which accomplishes the exact same thing.

Comment: Technically not *all* [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) - just those in the ASCII plane.